# How can I read json from url, output to app screen? SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I`m new at swift and need to read json file from url. I managed to get the data and output it to the console, but how can I get it to the application screen?

```
import SwiftUI

struct User: Codable {
    let Login: String
    let Password: String
}

struct AllTEC: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("asd").onAppear(perform: loadD)
    }
}

extension AllTEC
{
    func loadD() {

    let url = URL(string: "https://symbiosys-a415a.firebaseio.com/USER.json")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
              print("error: \(error!)")
              return
        }
        guard let data = data else{
              print("no data")
              return
        }
        guard let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data) else {
        print("Error: Couldn't decode data ito user")
        return
        }
        print("gotten user is \(user.Login)")
    }
    task.resume()
   }
}

struct AllTEC_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
          AllTEC()
    }
}
```

The json structure is pretty simple.

```
{
"Login":"Kapitan",
"Password":"M3030"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make a `@State` variable `user` for storing the returned `User` in `AllTEC`.

```
struct AllTEC: View {
    @State var user: User?
    var body: some View {
        Text("Login: \(user?.Login ?? "")")
            .onAppear(perform: loadD)
    }
}
```

And set `user` right after you decode it in the network call:

```
print("gotten user is \(user.Login)")
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.user = user
}
```